# Npm run watch not working changes in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have this issue in laravel I already run `npm run watch` and when I tried changing some value then save and when I refresh, it does not change. It would be great if anybody could figure out, thank you so much in advance!.

The thing is when I terminate and rerun the `npm run watch` it changes the update but it so hassle to terminate all over again in order to see the updates to your program
*what I tried*

```
npm watch-poll
```

I already tried clearing the cache on my chrome browser

I'm been using laragon is there any issue in my laragon? Or I guess the issue is on my chrome browser?

This is my package.json

```
{
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "postcss": "^8.1.14",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.20.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
},
"dependencies": {
    "vue-router": "^3.5.1"
}
}
```

*This is the file that I changed my index.vue* When I change the value from `Hello_value` into some value it didn't change

```
<template>
<div>
    <router-link v-bind:to="{name: 'home'}">Hello_value</router-link>
    <router-link v-bind:to="{name: 'second'}">Second</router-link>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
</template>
```

*I've been curious what's wrong using npm run watch* and I just starting learning laravue

Comment: What is the file that you changed?

Comment: @Muhammad Dyas Yaskur Thanks for your response I added the script above for what I'm been changing

Comment: take a look this https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/473

Answer (score 0):

Try updating package.json to the following and then run `npm install`.

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "mix --production"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21",
        "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
        "css-loader": "^5.2.7",
        "jquery": "^3.6",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.25",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "postcss": "^8.3.5",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^4.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.35.2",
        "sass-loader": "^12.1.0",
        "vue": "^2.6.14",
        "vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
    }
}
```